# generalize/automate data scraping from several different apartment websites(URLs) using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, json, algorithm, python-2.7, search

I would like to get specific apartment information (Name, Address, Phone and Rent) from several apartment websites using BeautifulSoup (BS). Most websites are designed differently and I was wondering if there is a technique  that I can use to generalize/automate the search using BS. For example, for the following two URLS

1. http://www.rentatbelleparkeast.com/Apartments/module/property_info/property%5Bid%5D/13578/
2. http://www.theparkmetro.com/Apartments/module/property_info/property%5Bid%5D/82248/

The following Python code (see also attached) is able scrape the needed data but not in the second one because of different design on the websites. To scrap the same data for the second website, I have to rename the class and attributes based on the HTML. My question (specifically) is how do I generalize the crawling to one, two, and n websites. n=1000+

#

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url=’http://www.rentatbelleparkeast.com/Apartments/module/property_info/property%5Bid%5D/13578/'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
#print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
#print soup

apt_list=[]

for item in soup:
    try:
        name = ''.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'limitedTitle'}).text.split())
except:
        name=''
    try:
        address = ''.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'limitedText'}).text.split())

    except:
        address=''
    try:
        address1 = ''.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'limitedText'}).text.split())

    except:
        address=''
    try:
        phone = ''.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'propertyContactText'}).text.split())
    except:
        phone=''
    try:
        rent1 = ''.join(soup.find('tr', {'class': 'alternate1'}).text.split())
    except:
        rent1=''
    try:
        rent2 = ''.join(soup.find('tr', {'class': 'alternate2'}).text.split())
except:
        rent2=''   
    try:
        rent3 = ''.join(soup.find('tr', {'class': 'alternate3'}).text.split())
    except:
        rent3=''      
    try:
        rent4 = ''.join(soup.find('tr', {'class': 'alternate4'}).text.split())
    except:
        rent=''

# Write data in a CSV file
    dat=[name, address, phone,  rent1, rent2]
    apt_list.append(dat)

print apt_list

with open ('filename1.csv','wb') as database:
    writer=csv.writer(database)
    for row in apt_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```